# Kafka Consumer Invalid Payload Error Handler

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have the below configuration. When the message is invalid I want to send an email and for errors I  want to save it in database. How can I handle this in errorHandler() ?

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableKafka
    public class KafkaConsumerConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer{
    @Bean
        ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
            return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((rec, ex) ->
            
            { dbService.saveErrorMsg(rec); }
          ,new FixedBackOff(5000, 3)) ;
            
        }
        
      
        @Override
        public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
              registrar.setValidator(this.validator);
            
        }

@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic", concurrency = "3", groupId = "mytopic-1-groupid")
    public void consumeFromTopic1(@Payload @Valid ValidatedClass val, ConsumerRecordMetadata meta) throws Exception
    {

        dbservice.callDB(val,"t");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your emai code is in `dbService.saveErrorMsg`.

Spring Boot should automatically detect the `ErrorHandler` `@Bean` and wire it into the container factory.

See Boot's `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` class and `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`.

Comment: Russel .Yes if message in the topic doesn't @Valid rules then i need to send email and for the rest of the error i need to save it in DB by calling `dbService.saveErrorMsg`.So can i distinguish between exception.i tried using `ex.getCause()`

Comment: So based on type of Exception thrown i need to handle error differently. For 1 set of exception :- `save in DB` and for invalid Json message `send email`.

Comment: Yes; you will need to add that logic to your recoverer - ex.getCause() should be the actual exception. The STCEH has exception classification but that is simply whether to retry or not retry and call the recoverer immediately. You should add the validation exception to the fatal exceptions since retry is not really appropriate for such problems. See `addNotRetryableExceptions(...)`.

Comment: what is STCEH? And doing `ex.getCause()` gave me `org.s.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void cKafKaConsumerService.consumeFromTopic1(model.ValidatedClass,org..ConsumerRecordMetadata) throws Exception: 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'val' on field 'bar': rejected value [1111]; codes [Max.val.bar,Max.bar,Max.int,Max]; arguments [o.s.c.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: ` .So do you mean if i have whenever there is invalid Json message then `MethodArgumentNotValidException` wil be thrown and

Comment: STCEH is short for `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` - right - in the case of validation failure, the cause is a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, which you should add to the `notRetryableExceptions`.

Comment: It's not getting retried by default So its fine. My doubt is how do I distinguish error caused by @Payload @Valid(invalid json)  .with other errors .I  got 2 types of error for invalid json `MessageConversionException` and `MethodArgumentNotValidException` .So is it possible to throw a custom exception eg. `InValidJsonOnTopic`

Comment: They represent two different problems - conversion exceptions are thrown for badly formed JSON, validation exceptions are from well-formed JSON but the contents failed validation. You could add a `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` to the `@KafkaListener` and throw a common exception, if you really don't care about the difference. But they really mean different things and I would expect you would want to convey more details about the problem in the email.

Comment: Only option I see not to use @Payload @Valid on Kafka listener and write a custom service to validate json. But it will mean  I need to write needless boilerplate code. If I use Common Exception then that common exception will be thrown in case of other issues too like timeout issue. etc. So it would not help. I just need to differentiate between All exceptions raised by ` @VALID @PAYLOAD ` and rest of the exceptions  in STCEH

Comment: As I said; you can add a `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` bean; put the bean name in `@KafkaListener.errorHandler` and in that error handler wrap the two exceptions in your one common exception and throw it. But I still don't understand why you can't check for both exceptions in your record recoverer.

Comment: Just last question do you mean to say I will only get 2 types of exceptions thrown by invalid json `@payload @valid` eg . `MessageConversionException` and `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.If yes then I can handle both exceptions in STCEH using something like `ex.getClause().equals("MessageConversionException").Is this what you are recommending

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant. Of course, you might throw other exceptions from your listener code that could be data related. It depends on how thorough the validation is.